# Initialize userChoice. If I set it to zero my program will compile

Tags: java, swing, user-input

before when I put `if(userChoice == 0)` it compiles just fine with no errors.  but that is setting the userchoice to constantly deposit no matter if they click the withdrawal button.  I need to figure out how to initialize userChoice as a keyboard input. I've tried `userChoice = ();` that doesn't work either.

this is the only if statement that works... but then my next if statement `if(userChoice ==1)` it is still going to deposit.??

```
int userChoice;

String[] menuItems = {"Deposit", "Withdrawal", "Print Account Information", "Exit"};
int selection;
selection = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, 
      "Please choose an item",
      bankAccount,
      JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
      JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, 
      null,
      menuItems,
      "Deposit");
System.out.println(selection);

if (userChoice == 0) {
    depositStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your deposit amount: $");
    deposit = Double.parseDouble(depositStr);
    initialBalance = initialBalance + deposit;
    selection = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Please choose an item",
      bankAccount,
      JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
      JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, 
      null,
      menuItems,
      "Deposit");
  System.out.println(selection);
}
```

and then i have more else if statements like else if (userChoice ==1) (1 aka withdrawal) ... it never egisters that the person hit 1

I have more if else statements. IT's just hard to keep spacing them by 4 spaces on here. My only compiling issue is that it says var userChoice is not initialized.

Comment: It's working for me. You seem to have forgotten an argument in `showOptionDialog`. You need to pass a `title` before the message for the option pane.

Comment: `userChoice` or `selection`?  Context is not clear - please add additional code.

Comment: I have it set so my options would be 0, 1, 2. 


PAss a title?
I'm very upset I've looked everywhere in our book for this but i does not contain it.

Comment: Can you show more of your code?

Comment: if (userChoice == 0)
   {
      
      depositStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your deposit amount: $");
      deposit = Double.parseDouble(depositStr);
      initialBalance = initialBalance + deposit;

   selection = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Please choose an item",
      bankAccount,
      JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
      JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, 
      null,
      menuItems,
      "Deposit");
   System.out.println(selection);
   }
   
   else if (userChoice == 1)
   {
      System.out.println("Enter your withdrawal amount: $");

Comment: Well that didn't work. the reason why i never post more of my code is because i haave it indented in JGrasp but I copy and paste here and have to go through indent four spaces every line for the code to show

Comment: keyboard input? have you tried using JTextField and get the value as user's input from the JTextField?

Comment: This code should work as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/13479889/2308683 Can you just put `else { System.out.println(selection + " " +menuItems[selection] ); }`?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing `userChoice` with `selection`, which would be the exact same thing in this context. It is always going to deposit because you are never setting the value of `userChoice`, so if you initialize as 0, it'll always be 0...

`JOptionPane.showOptionDialog` will *return the index of the item that has been selected*.

Therefore, you want this structure and remove `userChoice`

```
int selection = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(... , menuItems, ...);

System.out.printf("You selected %s at position %d%n", menuItems[selection], selection);

if (selection == 0) {

} else if (selection == 1) {

}
```

Comment: You're a hero!! Thank you so much. I've been looking around for a couple days but it's been hard to word this exact question. Thankkkk you. Very much appreciated!! 

P.S. it's always the easy things -_-